# A better way than counting the length of a list of units

Tags: list, haskell, idioms

I sometimes find myself writing code like this:

```
someFunc :: Foo -> Int
someFunc foo = length $ do
  x <- someList
  guard someGuard
  return ()
```

Or equivalently:

```
someFunc foo = length [() | x <- someList, someGuard]
```

Is there a better way to perform this sort of computation? More efficient? More readable? More idiomatic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you find yourself repeatedly programming to a pattern, the thing to do is write a higher-order function to encapsulate that pattern.  You could use the body you have, but in order to be utterly confident that your code is not allocating, I would recommend to use `foldl` and strict application of an increment operator:

```
numberSatisfying :: Integral n => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> n
numberSatisfying p = foldl (\n x -> if p x then (+1) $! n else n) 0
```

I have used QuickCheck to confirm this code equivalent to your original code.  (And yes, it is pretty cool that QuickCheck will test with random predicates.)

Answer (score 8):

Primo

```
guard someGuard
return ()
```

is redundant, `guard` already returns `()` if the condition is true. Then I suppose `someGuard` actually depends on `x`, otherwise it would be `if someGuard then length someList else 0`. The usual way to write it is

```
someFunc foo = filter (\x -> someGuard) someList
```

if the situation is really as simple as your example looks. For more complicated situations, using one of your example styles is the most direct way. I find the do-notation preferable if things get really complicated.

Comment: +1 Yes, `someList` depends on `foo`, and `someGuard` depends on both `foo` and `x`. The filter expression is probably the simplest way to capture that.